# Jquery set attribute from another attribute selected by a var

Tags: html, jquery, flask

I've been trying something I never did so here's my problem:

I use flask and a for loop to auto-import images for my gallery app, using 5 different folders that haves thumbs classed by year.

```
<div class="dsui-container 2016Container">
<div class="flex-wrap dsui-subcontainer flex-wrap-anim">
  {% for img in demilsez %}
  <div class="dsui-img-container z-depth-1" data-tilt style="cursor: pointer;">
    <img width="150" height="150" src="{{url_for("static", filename="demilsez/" + img)}}" class="dsui-img" style="pointer-events: none;" id="{{img | replace(".jpg", "")}}">
    <p class="dsui-hover hiddenDSH ubuntuB z-depth-1" style="pointer-events: none;">{{img}}</p>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
```

As they're thumbs I won't use them with my viewer, I want the pics in HQ. For that I created another folder with all the pics in hq png gif and all so the user don't load them untill they get imported in the page via JQ.

What I wanted to do is make spans with flask with an attribute having the path to the HQ img in its src attribute, to select the good one I've made the thumb and the span have the same id except the span have a V at the end,

```
{% for img in all %}
<span class="d-none" id="{{img | replace(".jpg", "") | replace(".png", "") | replace(".gif", "") | replace(".mp4", "")}}V" src="{{url_for("static", filename="all/" + img)}}"></span>
{% endfor %}
```

In my script I use this variable to get the id of the span containing the path to the hq image

```
var $vid = $(this).find('img').attr('id');
```

then I use `$vid` to get the path with something like that

`alert ($('#' + $vid + 'V').attr('src'))`

but it returns undefined..

What I want to do with the result is simply changing one of my element attribute with the path (element is `#viewer-img`) but I don't know how.

(I'm not a backend dev only front and this is very new to me so it's normal if what I do seems crazy and sorry if I wrote a lot)

Comment: A `span` is having an `src`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the question :s

Comment: `<span class="d-none" id="{{img | replace(".jpg", "") | replace(".png", "") | replace(".gif", "") | replace(".mp4", "")}}V" src="{{url_for("static", filename="all/" + img)}}"></span>`

Comment: here span has `src` attribute?

Comment: `<span class="d-none" id="GT_BannerV" src="/all/GT_Banner.png"></span>` is what it will look like on the site so I want to set the `src` attribute of my `#viewer-img` using the span `src` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my prob and finished my app already

basically had to rework the images name then I was able to use them with JQ and I simply did a var for the good src and it worked.